# “zum Leben/Essen” or “für das Leben/Essen”

Tags: difference, preposition

Can *zu* and *für* be used interchangeably with *das Leben* or *das Essen* and similar nominalized verbs?

> Das Geld reicht **für das** Leben.
>   Das Geld reicht **zum** Leben.
>
> Die Menschen nehmen sich kaum noch genug Zeit **für das** Essen.
>   Die Menschen nehmen sich kaum noch genug Zeit **zum** Essen.

Comment: Do you by 'similar words' mean 'nominalized verbs'?

Comment: @c.p. Exactly! I'm going to edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is it coincidence that you chose *leben* and *essen,* i.e., two verbs that are a special case regarding your question?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It's just that it was easier to come up with examples for these two words where I didn't see any difference in meaning. But now thanks to your explanations it has become a bit clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In most cases,** the two can be used interchangably. For example, I do not see a difference in meaning between:

> Sie gab das Signal zum Wenden.
>   Sie gab das Signal fürs Wenden.
>   Sie gab das Signal für das Wenden.
>   *She gave the signal to turn.*
>
> Ich bin zu alt zum Fallschirmspringen.
>   Ich bin zu alt fürs Fallschirmspringen.
>   Ich bin zu alt für das Fallschirmspringen.
>   *I am too old for skydiving.*

However, I would consider *zum* here to be much more idiomatic than *fürs,* which is in turn more idiomatic than *für das.*

---

The first exception from this I can think of is when **the nominalised verb has an additional meaning** that the regular verb does not. For example, *das Leben* cannot only refer to the process of living but also to a life as a whole. So, there actually is a difference in the following example of yours:

> Das Geld reicht zum Leben.
>   Das Geld reicht für das Leben.

The first variant can only refer to the process of living, i.e., the money we are talking about here suffices to sustain living, e.g.:

> Mein Gehalt reicht zum Leben.
>   *My salary allows me to live.*

The second variant can **additionally** refer to life as a whole, e.g.:

> Dieser Lottogewinn reicht fürs Leben.
>   *This lottery win will last for life.*

Something similar applies to *das Essen,* which may also refer to the whole ritual arond consuming food, while the verb *essen* is more narrow. This allows for a small nuance in your second example:

> Die Menschen nehmen sich kaum noch genug Zeit zum Essen.
>   Die Menschen nehmen sich kaum noch genug Zeit für das Essen.

In the first case, people do hardly take their time for consuming food at all. The second case could also refer to people not taking their time anymore to sit around a table and dine but instead consume their food during other activities.

Also note that such substantiations can evolve their own meaning when referring to a special event. For instance, in a particular context, *Fallschirmspringen* in the above example can refer to a special skydiving event and not skydiving in general. For example, one could say:

> Ich bin zu alt für das jährliche Weihnachtsfallschirmspringen. Aber im Sommer werde ich wieder fallschirmspringen.
>   *I am to alt for the annual Christmas skydiving. But I will go skydiving again in summer.*

The example given in [Jan’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22930/2594) is another instance of this.

---

A second exception is **when *für* means *in exchange for* or similar**. Here, you cannot replace *fürs* or *für das* with *zum.* For example in the following sentence:

> Sie gab ihm 10 € fürs Rasenmähen.
>   *She gave him 10 € for mowing the lawn.*

This is particular weird, if *für* can be mean both, *in exchange for* and *to* like in the following example:

> Sie gibt ihm 10 € zum Einkaufen.
>   Sie gibt ihm 10 € fürs Einkaufen.

In the first case, she gives him money so he can then go buy something. The second case can **also** mean that he already went shopping and she gives him 10 € to compensate his expenses.

---

Finally, there are some **fixed expressions**, which require *zum,* e.g.:

> Es ist zum Heulen.
>   *It makes you cry. – It is pathetic.*

Answer (score 7):

No they can't. This might be true for a lot of cases, but they can have subtly different meanings:

> Das Geld reicht **zum Essen.**
>   Das Geld reicht **für das Essen.**

The first sentence implies that whatever money the speaker gets is enough to keep her fed (while also implying that it's not enough for much else).

The sencond sentence, on the other hand, implies that the money the speaker has *at the moment* is enough for whichever exquisite, expensive or otherwise costly food she wants to buy right now (or maybe tonight at the latest).

Generally, I would say that the *für* forms are more likely to be understood as one-time statements (hence accusative), while *zu* with the dative are more likely to be understood as long-term statements. This is analogous to what is used for locations: If a preposition is followed by a dative, it is understood to mean *being somewhere*, as with *im Haus*, *im Garten*. If, however, the accusative is used, it is understood as a *movement towards somewhere*: *in das Haus*, *in den Garten*.

Comment: I don't quite understand your last paragraph. How does accusative vs. dative have an effect on our understanding of time (one-time vs. long-term)?

Comment: @stillenat I added another two lines to explain that. What I meant is that with locations, *preposition <dative>* is understood to mean *being there*, while *preposition <accusative>* is understood to mean *moving somewhere* — the former is a state while the latter is an action.